# Issue with programmatically trying to set a FrameLayout for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I am able to successfully a achieve this doing so with the XML layout as seen in the image below:

[image]

Then when trying to do so within Java I am not able to get the same result as seen in the screen shot:

[image]

Here is the Java code I have that renders the result above:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this.context);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);


ImageView bodyImageView = new ImageView(this.context);
bodyImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.niners);


TextView bodyTextView = new TextView(this.context);
bodyTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
bodyTextView.setText("SF");
bodyTextView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
bodyTextView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);


frameLayout.addView(bodyImageView);
frameLayout.addView(bodyTextView);
```

Can anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong?

### UPDATE:

Based on the response below the screen shot results in the following:

[image]

Comment: The XML attributes that start with `layout_` are settings for the `LayoutParams` on the `View`, not for the `View` itself. You need to create a `LayoutParams` for the `TextView` to account for the `layout_width`, `_height`, and `_gravity`; e.g., `new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.Bottom)`. The `ImageView` doesn't necessarily need any, since the `FrameLayout` wraps it. You'll want to fix the `setGravity()` call, too, and unless the `FrameLayout` itself is inside another `FrameLayout`, it might not make sense to be setting `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` on it.

Comment: Not sure how you got this result using layout, logically the parent is `wrap_content`, and the `TextView` is `match_parent`; then it means `wrap_content` and that you got programmatically.. Let me know If you're interested with any other type of layout other than `FrameLayout`

Comment: @Zain I am not married to framelayout, but from my understanding, framelayout is the only layout that can be used to overlay one element over another?! I need the image view to be in the "background" and the textview in the "foreground" over the imageview, as seen in the first image.

Comment: Zain makes a good point about the `TextView` that I didn't think of. You can correct that with its `layout_gravity`, though, which you can change to `Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` in the code. (Unless you do actually want that gray stripe along the bottom from the background. It's unclear, now, what you're going for exactly.)

Comment: @MikeM. Yes the gray stripe is also wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the layout gravity as a `LayoutParams` to the `TextView`:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

And change the gravity of the the `TextView` to the center:

```
bodyTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Here's the entire layout:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this.context);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);


ImageView bodyImageView = new ImageView(this.context);
bodyImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.niners);

TextView bodyTextView = new TextView(this.context);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
bodyTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
bodyTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
bodyTextView.setText("SF");
bodyTextView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
bodyTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
frameLayout.addView(bodyImageView);
frameLayout.addView(bodyTextView);

setContentView(frameLayout);
```

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!!!!! IT WORKS EXACTLY AS I NEEDED!!!!

Answer (score -1):

I change to kotlin sorry but, test this code

```
       val frameLayout = FrameLayout(this)
        val layoutparams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
        )

        frameLayout.layoutParams = layoutparams
        
        val bodyImageView = ImageView(this)
        bodyImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

        val params =
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM

        val bodyTextView = TextView(this)

        bodyTextView.text = "SF"
        bodyTextView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        bodyTextView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)

        bodyTextView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.purple_700)

        frameLayout.addView(bodyImageView)
        frameLayout.addView(bodyTextView,params)
```

You only have to add parameters to your view

in Java

```
        // Add this code
           FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutparams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        // Add in your code for textView
        frameLayout.addView(bodyTextView,layoutparams);
```

Comment: I get the following error `Cannot resolve method 'setGravity' in 'LayoutParams'` for the line of code: `layoutparams.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);`

Comment: sorry, i Updated,

Comment: It still does not work, I have updated the screen shot result based on the code you provided above. Could you please provide the complete code based on my above and your suggestions in your answer please.